# Datatable values are not accessible

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datatable

I have a datatable where in the items in it are filled by back end. When i debug, datatable is not null and datarow is also not null. But Particular items are not found.i.e.But ItemCode and ItemName are null :(

```
if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        log.Debug("inside the for loop fnRecordExist");

        TextBox Itemcode = (TextBox)Grid_GRNEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("Item_Code");
        TextBox ItemName = (TextBox)Grid_GRNEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("Item_Name");

        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
        if (drCurrentRow != null)
        {
            Itemcode.Text = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["ItemCode"].ToString();
            ItemName.Text = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item_Name"].ToString();
            rowIndex++;
        }
    }

    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
}
```

Comment: The values which are null aren't being taken from the datatable at all... so what does this have to do with a datatable? You're just trying to find controls in a grid... and I suspect that the relevant grid doesn't have a control called "Item_Code" / "Item_Name"...

Answer (score 0):

user3781993, please check your fieldname in datatable and the time of accessing it. At one place its ItemCode and other its Item_Code